# Load one of multiple items from API result that has a "list / set"

Tags: json, api, curl, get

I have a API result that contains multiple photo's in a set / list / childs (I do not know the right term), the result looks like this.

```
"photos":[{"small":"https:\/\/pararius-office-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net\/10379\/files\/photos\/api-little\/52016521.1667319824-357.jpeg?fit=crop&width=100&height=100",
"big":"https:\/\/pararius-office-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net\/10379\/files\/photos\/api-export\/52016521.1667319824-357.jpeg?width=600",
"huge":"https:\/\/pararius-office-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net\/10379\/files\/photos\/api-huge\/52016521.1667319824-357.jpeg?width=1000&fit=bounds",
"middle":"https:\/\/pararius-office-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net\/10379\/files\/photos\/api-middle\/52016521.1667319824-357.jpeg?width=1000&fit=bounds",
"category":"photo"}]
```

I want to shot the big photo but I don't know how.
The rest is working fine.

[image: my code]

I tried to load it with '. $property->city . ' but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to get the 'big' photo from "photos".

I start by copying your photo data into `$results`.

```
echo '<pre>';

$results = '"photos":[{"small":"https:\/\/pararius-office-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net\/10379\/files\/photos\/api-little\/52016521.1667319824-357.jpeg?fit=crop&width=100&height=100",
"big":"https:\/\/pararius-office-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net\/10379\/files\/photos\/api-export\/52016521.1667319824-357.jpeg?width=600",
"huge":"https:\/\/pararius-office-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net\/10379\/files\/photos\/api-huge\/52016521.1667319824-357.jpeg?width=1000&fit=bounds",
"middle":"https:\/\/pararius-office-prod.global.ssl.fastly.net\/10379\/files\/photos\/api-middle\/52016521.1667319824-357.jpeg?width=1000&fit=bounds",
"category":"photo"}]';
echo "$results\n\n";
```

I then get a substring from the 10th character, removing `photos:[` 
Remove the slashes.
And trim the trailing `]`.
We now have valid JSON.

```
$results = stripslashes(trim(substr($results,10),']'));
echo "$results\n\n";
```

To confirm the JSON is now valid I convert it to an array.

```
$results = json_decode($results,1);
var_export($results);
```

I then get the 'big' photo src.

```
$src = $results['big'];
echo "\n\nsrc = $src\n\n";
echo '</pre>';
```

Then show the photo:

```
echo "<img src=\"$src\" />";
```

The Result:

[image: Resulting Page]